# Laravel9: route parameter always missing in validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel v9.2.1 + Laravel Sanctum v2.14.1

I got a route

```
DELETE /api/v1/auth/tokens/{token}
```

for example (the `token` is an uuid)

```
DELETE http://example.com/api/v1/auth/tokens/5fcfa274-81d8-4e9f-8feb-207db77531af
```

And I am sure it works as expected via `php artisan route:list`
[image]

Before handling by the Controller, it should be validated by a FormRequest

**app/Http/Controllers/V1/Auth/TokensController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\V1\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\V1\Auth\Tokens\{
    DestroyRequest,
};

class TokensController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(DestroyRequest $request) {
        $request->user()->tokens()->where('id', $request->token)->first()->delete();
        return response()->noContent();
    }
}
```

**app/Http/Requests/V1/Auth/Tokens/DestroyRequest.php**

```php
class DestroyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'regex:/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i', 
                Rule::exists('personal_access_tokens')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('tokenable_id', $this->user()->id);
                }),                         
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

---

### But what I only got is *The token field is required*

### I had already pass the `token`, why the `'required'` rule still working?

[image]

---

#### What I tried

Only if I pass the token parameter like below, it will work

```
DELETE /api/auth/tokens/something?token=test_regex_is_working
```

[image]

I try to `dd($this->token)` in **app/Http/Requests/V1/Auth/Tokens/DestroyRequest.php**, it works as expected.

[image]

Comment: use route parameter validation like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i might try going about it differently as the token isn't really user input

In the routes file:

```php
Route::delete('/api/v1/auth/tokens/{token}', [TokensController::class, 'destroy'])->whereUuid('token');
```

In the `FormRequest` something maybe like this:

```php
public function authorize()
{
    return DB::table('personal_access_tokens')
        ->where('tokenable_id', Auth::id())
        ->where('token', $this->route('token'))
        ->exists()
}
```

Comment: when using ```->whereUuid('token')``` laravel will return a ```404``` instead of a validation exception when the token doesn't match the giver regex

Comment: non optional route parameters are required so we don't need that rule either. we also don't really need to validate a string when we are using regex and laravel (default) doesn't cast the route params which is default a string

Answer (score 5):

You might need to add the following in the FormRequest class:

```php
protected function prepareForValidation() 
    {
        $this->merge(['token' => $this->route('token')]);
    }
```

I believe URL parameters are not included in the request directly.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of both [@RawSlugs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10917416/rawslugs) and [@Aaron T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19459663/aaron-t), thank them a lot!

**app/Http/Requests/V1/Auth/Tokens/DestroyRequest.php**

```php
protected function prepareForValidation() {
    $this->merge(['token' => $this->route('token')]);
}

public function authorize() {
    return $this->user()->tokens()->where('id', $this->token)->exists();
}

// But since the authorize() will validate the request before rules(), this will be useless
public function rules() {
    return [
        'token' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'regex:/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i',                       
        ]
    ];
}
```

I'm using Laravel Sanctum.